# how do I grab the text inside of a form_label?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I currently have a`form_label`in my view as follows:

```
echo form_label('cat', 'cat');
```

I want to be able to set a variable in the controller to equal **'cat'** as is displayed in the label.

In my controller I have tried using post and get to access the contents, but got done reason it only works got form_input and not `form_label.`

Thank you!

Comment: please show your controller code. Form_label will accept variables like any other function

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to pass the same text into a hidden element in the form so you can grab it from the post object.